# Is memcached server response out of order?

Tags: memcached, xmemcached

If I have a client that creates a TCP connection, and send multiple commands to the memcached server, will server guarantee to respond to these commands in the same order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memcached always sends responses in order.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you tell me where I can find this information? Some wiki, documents, etc? I think it depends on the implementation of memcached server right?

Comment: Well, there's should only be one implementation of the server and the server will only process one command at a time per connection. I'm not aware of any documentation that explains this, but I've worked on the memcached code pretty extensively. You should be able to examine any of the clients or the server to see that this is the case.